# My whole Ubuntu OS is really Laggy

Tags: 13.04

I just upgraded my computer from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.04.  The problem: it is EXTREMELY laggy.   I ran it off my CDROM first to test the waters and it was laggy then too, but I assumed that was because I was running it from the CDROM.  Now it's fully installed but everything is laggy except the pointer (even typing).

Comment: What hardware specs do you have? Edit your question with this information.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your computer can't handle the Unity desktop environment and is trying to make up with software acceleration. Try installing the lubuntu-desktop package and selecting it before you log-in. If I recall correctly (I'm not at an Ubutntu PC right now), you will see a small Ubuntu logo by your user name. Click that and you should get a list of the different desktop environments installed. Select LXDE. Not as flashy as Unity, but it should get the job done.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else having the same issue in the future; In my case it was the drivers that needed to be installed. (In my case it was Nvidia Drivers) - I would suggest that you also update and upgrade the system. (For me nearly every time awhile ago I tried to install ubuntu, it would be very very **laggy** but after drivers -> installed and OS -> updated & upgraded, + reboot: It would work flawlessly)

Now, this maybe - may or may not work; But in case it would work I'm posting this.
+It would maybe work for others in the future.

Regards